# How to vectorize performing pairwise sums given two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two numpy arrays which look like this:

```
x = [v1, v2, v3, ..., vm]
y = [w1, w2, w3, ..., wn]
```

where `vi, wj` are numpy arrays of length 3.

I want to perform a pairwise *summation* of v's and w's and get a final array

```
z = [v1+w1, v1+w2,...,v1+wn,v2+w1, ..., vi+wj, ..., vm+wn]
```

A simple way of obtaining `z` is as follows:

```
z = np.zeros ((m*n, 3))
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        z[n*i+j] = x[i] + y[j]
```

This computation is not feasible is `m, n` are very large.

I know scipy.spatial has methods to enumerate pairwise distances using distance_matrix in a vectorized fashion.

I want to ask if there is a vectorized version of performing such pairwise *additions* for numpy arrays?

Comment: What are the shapes of `v_i` and `w_i`? Are they compatible? Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes, v_i and w_i are compatible, numpy arrays of length 3. x is mx3 matrix, y is a nx3 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of broadcasting, creating a 2D array, then you can easily get `z[i,j] = x[i] + y[j]`

```
x = np.reshape(x, (-1, 1)) # shape (N, 1)
y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1)) # shape (N, 1)
z = x + y.T # shape (N, N)
```

If you want to have z as a 1D array you can do `z.reshape(-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If x is mx3 matrix, y is a nx3

```
x.shape # (m,3)
y.shape # (n,3)

x1 = x.reshape(m,1,3)      
y1 = y.reshape(1,n,3)
z = x1 + y1     # shape (m,n,3)
z1 = z.reshape(-1,3)   # (m*n, 3)
```

equivalently

```
 z = x[:,None]+y
```

test:

```
In [263]: x=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3); y=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)    
In [264]: z = x[:,None]+y    
In [265]: z.shape
Out[265]: (4, 2, 3)
    
In [266]: z
Out[266]: 
array([[[ 0,  2,  4],
        [ 3,  5,  7]],

       [[ 3,  5,  7],
        [ 6,  8, 10]],

       [[ 6,  8, 10],
        [ 9, 11, 13]],

       [[ 9, 11, 13],
        [12, 14, 16]]])
```